# Kendo UI Grid - with javascript, Filter "OR" default option

Tags: filter, kendo-ui, grid, kendo-grid

Currently for the grid filter if I set:

```
filterable{extra:true}
```

then two filter appear. The default logical operator is `AND` between those two.

Can we change it to `OR`?

Comment: Please show the complete snippet with the information for all columns etc.

Comment: I don't think it is possible.  Looking at the source for FilterMenu.js, the templates for the menus don't seem to have any programmatic way to change anything in the And/Or, they are just listed.  Only way would be to change the template(s) and re-build.

Comment: An example if the grid with the and or drop down can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/loanburger/re05vvrj/  I would have thought you could change the default logical operator after the grid databound but sadly have not been able to do so.

Comment: I found a way to remove 'And' completely and force it to be 'Or' (which is useful for an enum binding).  But still no default to Or.

Comment: @freedomn-m: can u tell me how u removed 'And' completely ?
I need to remove 'Or' completely.